# Should the Reverse DNS for an EC2 point to the Public DNS or the domain name?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

In trying to set up a mail server (for fun!), I [requested a Reverse DNS](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) from Amazon, specifying my Elastic IP and my mail server subdomain (e.g. mail.mydomain.com).
A Reverse DNS Lookup now returns my EC2 Public DNS.

e.g.

> $ dig -x 5.4.3.2 +short
>   ec2-5-4-3-2.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

I expected that the reverse lookup would instead point to my domain name ('mail.mydomain.com').

1) Is my expectation wrong? Should a Reverse Lookup point the EC2 public DNS or to the requested domain name?
2) Is the `dig` result because I missed something? Such as additionally making a PTR record in Route53 and/or configuring something in apache (such as a proxy or alias)?

System: I have a t2-micro (using an EIP and Route53) running ubuntu 14.04 and apache2 with a few sites. And I'm following this [mail server tutorial](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/).

Thanks! There's a lot to this mail server stuff!

Comment: You shouldn't need to set up PTRs or anything else, other than your `mail.example.com` `A` record.  Does `dig @8.8.8.8` (non-AWS DNS server) return the right answer?

Comment: Do you mean does any other server return an answer?  `dig @8.8.8.8` does return an answer.  `dig @<my elastic IP>` returns ```; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached```

Comment: Sorry, my question was whether 8.8.8.8 (Google public DNS) returns the *expected* answer -- the hostname you provided when you requested the assignment from AWS support.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know about google public DNS. `dig @8.8.8.8 mail.example.com` does return the correct IP now.

Comment: One thing that was missing was an A record for mail.mydomain.com in my Route53 record set. The MX record points from the domain to the mail server (`mydomain.com` to `10 mail.mydomain.com`) (I'm still not clear on what the "10" is for.) Then the mail server's name still has to point to an IP,   thus an A record is needed.

Comment: And the PTR record isn't needed because that is what the AWS request for is for. Amazon handles the PTR record for you.

Comment: The "10" is the priority/preference/cost factor.  When you have more than one MX, the sending server is supposed to try the lowest number, first... so an MX of 5 would outrank 10.  With just one, the value doesn't matter.  So, to my original question, is the reverse lookup of the IP now correctly returning the hostname you expect, or the generic obe?

Comment: Don't SMTP MTAs check reverse lookup for peer IPs against the name in HELO/EHLO any more? You could put the AWS-given reverse lookup in your HELO, of course, but it might change... (On Azure the API lets you specify your own FQDN on a PublicIP, though for security the forward record has to be in place first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reverse DNS for an EC2 will point to the public DNS.

```
$ dig -x 5.4.3.2 +short
```

would return

```
ec2-5-4-3-2.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

and not

```
mail.mydomain.com
```